# Processing: disable double buffering in debug mode

Tags: processing

For teaching programming in the Processing Language, I would like to use the debugger in the IDE so that students can experience the control flow in a program like

```
void primitives ( int x, int y ) {
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    circle( x, y - 10, 20 - ( i << 2 ) );
    final int yi = y + ( i << 1 );
    line( x - 10, yi, x + 10, yi );
  }
}

void setup () {
  size( 200, 200 );
}

void draw () {
  primitives( 70, 50 );
  primitives( 30, 170 );
  primitives( 130, 150 );
}
```

However, the graphics statements only show their effects each time after `draw` finishes.
Probably, Processing double buffers the bitmap for smooth performance
in production runtime and only copies into the frame buffer after `draw` has completed.
At debug time, I would like that graphics are drawn instantaneously as the students step through the program in the debugger. Is there a way to do?

Comment: AFAIK that isn't currently possible but would be a super useful teaching tool. One idea that comes to mind is implementing a [Processing IDE Tool](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Tool-Overview) or extension to the Debugger that spawns a "debug" PApplet which renders one drawing instruction at a time based on the debugger step.